# How to open location permission settings in Android 30?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to open directly location permission settings on button click android 30. How can I open?

[image]

Below is my code. this navigates me on permission page,

```
final Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution yet..@user1443721

Comment: @VishalVaishnav the solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63487691/4548520 you don't need intent, you just need to grant `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission, and if it was granted then try to grant `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` and it automatically will open the system location permission page for the app, don't forget that you need to show should show UI with rationale for requesting a permission https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting read about `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`

Answer (score 10):

First request permission for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION (or coarse). Then if you got the permission, request permission for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION. It will open directly the app location settings but only if you have **Target SDK 30**.

Comment: This only works the very first time . I don't know why google don't say the reason of this.

Comment: Probably Google wants for users to know how to give/block permissions manually from the system screen and in the process, they make our developer life harder.

Comment: yes i agree this is a joke for user experience... seems google don't care about it.

Comment: @GilbertoIbarra Is there a tracking issue for this one-shot background permission behavior?

Comment: @TWiStErRob This is the expected behavior , is not an issue, just follow the google recomendations to show the permissions, and not a custom flow .

Answer (score 0):

Since now, there is no way to open directly permission selection page in android.
Android 11 provides deep linking to open permission selection page directly if user ask for background location.

Otherwise there is no other way to open permission selection page directly.