# Android-11: How to open system location permission settings screen programmatically?

Tags: android, android-11

When targeting Android 11/API 30, applications will no longer have the ability to request access to location data all of the time from within an application — this option has been removed from the in-app permissions dialog. If an application wants permission to access the users location all the time when in the background, the permission will need to be granted from within the system settings screen for your application.
I know I can set it from the phone's settings, app info, location permissions...
By this way, I have to open "Settings" manually. How can I use an Intent to start the activity of location permission settings for my App programmatically inside my app?

Comment: Found the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669828/how-to-open-location-permission-settings-in-android-30.

Comment: so it's duplicate, please delete it, Android 30 API allows automatically open it if `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` was granted and then you request again location permission but this time background https://stackoverflow.com/a/63487691/4548520