# android studio open location permission page directly

Tags: android

I am working on android app where I need to allow the app to access location and I am looking for a way to make the user go directly to access location setting page where he can find the options:
allow all the time,
allow only while using the app
ask every time
don't allow

I tried using the blow code but it takes the user to app info page:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
      Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", PACKAGE_NAME, null);
      intent.setData(uri);
      startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669828/how-to-open-location-permission-settings-in-android-30/63487691#63487691  Please search for answers before posting a new one.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick!

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings. ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
        .putExtra(android.provider.Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName()));
```

Comment: thanks for the replay but this open notification access permission and I want location access setting

Comment: So sorry, misread. I edited the answer with the proper destination.

Comment: thanks for the replay but this open location access setting in general and I want to open location permission for the my app